# Error while obtaining information about the database? In EclipseLink with Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I am doing a small application with **eclipselink** . When am trying to insert data into database it's throwing an Exception.

Used Technologies are:

IDE:         Eclipse
ORM:         EclipseLink
Platform:    JAVA
Database:    Oracle

Previously I worked with MySql it's worked fine. When I changed my Database the problem is occurred.

Below is **persistance.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="OracleDemo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.demo.UserDetails</class>
<properties>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="testjpa" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="testjpa"/>

        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />            
        <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name"  value="createDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc" />
        <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="dropDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My **InsertData.java** class

```
public class InsertData {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
    userDetails.setName("prabha");
    userDetails.setCity("SKLM");

    EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getEmf().createEntityManager();
    try {
        EntityTransaction entr = entityManager.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();

        entityManager.persist(userDetails);

        entr.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
}
```

**Exception**

```
[EL Info]: 2014-03-17 15:15:32.603--ServerSession(799611093)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2014-03-17 15:15:32.801--ServerSession(799611093)--Exception [EclipseLink-4019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Error while obtaining information about the database. Refer to  the nested exception for more details.
 Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception  [EclipseLink-4019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5):  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
 Exception Description: Error while obtaining information about the database. Refer to the nested exception for more details.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:766)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
at com.demo.ReadData.main(ReadData.java:14)
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
  Exception Description: Error while obtaining information about the database. Refer to the nested exception for more details.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.errorRetrieveDbMetadataThroughJDBCConnection(DatabaseException.java:368)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:226)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
... 5 more
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace (TEXT!) instead of a image for which one needs additional glasses.

Comment: @AndreiI Just right click on Image and select **Open Image in New Tab** if it's not i will upload. thank you

Comment: @Prabha Which Oracle version you are using and What Driverusing

Comment: @codegeek Oracle11g and ojdbc14.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offical JAR file in combination with **JDK 1.6** is ojdbc6.jar.When your using with **Oracle11g** instead of using **ojdbc14.jar** use **ojdbc6.jar**.